# intrinsicContentSize for UITableView centered in its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib, ios-autolayout

I want to center a subclassed tableview (TSNInformationTableView) in its superview using xib file.

[image]

The height of the table is set using a custom intrinsic size:

[image]

The issue is the table can have a dynamic size/height, different number of cells with different text inside of them. So in the TSNInformationTableView I have defined the *intrinsicContentSize* method:

```
- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize {

        return self.contentSize
}
```

The problem I have with the self.contentSize.height is it does not return the correct height of the table but something somewhat smaller. That is why I tried to compensate this with the multiplier 1.45. It does not scale properly with different number od the cells.

In the image there is a visible cut of the last cell because the height of the table defined by the intrinsicContentSize is not correct.

[image]

The table is initialized with the following code:

```
self.informationTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
self.informationTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

[self.informationTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

**UPDATE**

I had to add this method in the controller where the table view (TSNInformationTableView) is nested:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if(!self.isInformationTableViewLoaded) {
        self.isInformationTableViewLoaded = YES;

        [self.InformationTableView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
        [self.InformationTableView setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

isInformationTableViewLoaded is just a simple BOOL property in the controller indicating that the table has been created (so that we can get proper table view size). It works without any animation issue now.

Also the table's estimatedRowHeight should be set to e.g. 1000.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use height and width constraints to size the TableView? (which you can dynamically/programmatically update by connecting them as outlets)

Comment: I was using it. But I do not know the height of the table before it is created. The intrinsicContent size method I used in the presented implementation results in the same layout.  I could update it with any correct value. Obviously tableview.contentSize is not the right one even after the table is painted. I do not know why. I'm not using any headers/footers.

Comment: What kind of data do you display in the cells? Do you have cells with different (dynamic) heights? (by the way, what is the image with 'sdfsdfsf' in your post supposed to be?)

Comment: @Kymer The number of cells and the text can vary, that is why I can not set the height of the table. First the autolayout has to kick in and intrinsicConentSize is documented way to help it to get the correct height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews  in the controller where the table is nested. See the edit at the end of the original post.